# ServiceWorker doesn't load Images

Tags: javascript, polymer, service-worker, polymer-starter-kit

I working on implementing the [Service Worker technology] into a site.

Everything works as expected except for **Images**.

Images aren't loaded at all.

I wonder if this is expected behaviour, or if images are supposed to load.

To reproduce this error, I made a fresh installation of the `Polymer Starter Kit` and just added one line into the first view `my-view1.html`

```
<img src="../images/cat.png" alt="">
```

I added the image to the according directory.

If you proceed and disable your wifi, you'll see that the page is still loading as expected. Only the cat image will not load.

I am using:

- Polymer-CLI v0.17.0
- Ubuntu v16.04
- node v4.2.6
- npm v3.5.2

### Question

Are Images supposed to load with Service Worker? And if yes, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `sw-precache-config.js`, just add the files you want to cache:

```
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
    '/index.html',
    '/manifest.json',
    '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js',
  ],
  navigateFallback: 'index.html',
};
```

Currently, only `index.html`, `manifest.json`, and `webcomponents-lite.min.js` are registered to get cached by the service worker.

```
module.exports = {
  staticFileGlobs: [
    '/index.html',
    '/manifest.json',
    '/images/mycat.png',
    '/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js',
  ],
  navigateFallback: 'index.html',
};
```

Comment: Amazing technology. I did as you said and updated my demo. Everything works fine now.

Comment: You can also use a `*` to include all images like this: *'/images/**/*.jpg'*

Answer (score 2):

I have just checked your demo. "cat.png" is not seem to be in the list of items to be cached. I think you should add it manually or you should add a file filter in sw-precache config.

I think [example usage for sw-precache](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache#example) illustrates what you need;

```
  swPrecache.write(`${rootDir}/service-worker.js`, {
    staticFileGlobs: [rootDir + '/**/*.{js,html,css,png,jpg,gif,svg,eot,ttf,woff}'],
    stripPrefix: rootDir
  }, callback);
```

Other than that SW's [Cache Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) stores `request - response pairs`, for which content doesn't really matter.

> The Cache interface provides a storage mechanism for Request / Response object pairs that are cached, for example as part of the ServiceWorker life cycle.

You can cache practically anything may it be images, fonts, sounds, html, json, videos or else.